# how to get auto count resgister number nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i need to add auto count on Register number  on Input box , like SD010,NEXT SD011..SD012..SD013..
using nodejs and mongodb how ? any idea ?

like picture below,when am open entry form need to check last entry and load next register number on textbox [see image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldegK.jpg)

[see image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ4Ye.jpg)

my mongodb connection code:

```
const mongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const state={ db:null };
module.exports.connect = function(done) { 
                            const url='mongodb://localhost:27017';
                            const dbname='stock';
                            mongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
                                if(err) 
                                    return done(err) 
                                state.db=data.db(dbname);
                                done()
                            })
                        } 
module.exports.get = function(){ 
                        return state.db 
                    }
```

Comment: const mongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient
    const state={
        db:null
    }
    module.exports.connect=function(done) {
        const url='mongodb://localhost:27017'
        const dbname='stock'
    
     mongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
            if(err) return done(err)
            state.db=data.db(dbname)
            done()
        })
        
    }
    
    module.exports.get=function(){
        return state.db
    }

Comment: Please update your question with the details you provided in the comment.

Comment: @Avani Khabiya i can't add on question ,already tried to add mongoDB connection code in my question but i can't post due to some format errors of stackoverflow

Comment: If your question is not readable enough, people will not be able to help you efficiently. Adding your code in the question itself.

Comment: problem solved and make it auto count system  self with friends ,...